# How does Flink save state in checkpoint/savepoint if some of state descriptor is removed

Tags: apache-flink

If I have a simple flink job with 2 keyed states, say State1 and State2.

The job is configured with rocksDB backend. Each of the states hold 10GB data.

If I update the code so that one of the state is not used(state descriptor deleted, and related code removed.). For example State1 is deleted.

When next time flink trigger checkpoint or I trigger savepoint manually.
Will the checkpoint/savepoint still hold data of State1 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RocksDB with incremental checkpoints, then state for the obsolete state descriptor will remain in checkpoints until it is compacted away (but it can be ignored). With any full snapshot, nothing of State1 will remain.

With RocksDB, expired state is eventually removed by a RocksDB compaction filter. Until then, if `StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired`  is set the state backend returns null in the place of expired values.

[Documentation on State TTL](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl)

Comment: If I enable incremental checkpoint, When will the data be compacted away? I read the doc and know that there are two kinds of "compaction": 1. rocksDB compaction will happen when delete api is called and done in background. 2. flink use rocksDb metadata file and "compact" useless sst files across checkpoints. I guess #1 will not happen to data in State1. So does it mean that when flink triggers an incremental checkpoint, it will delete rocksDB database of State1? Could you explian more detail on "(but it will be ignored)"?

Comment: I've expanded my answer; hopefully it's clearer now.